In the Rocky Horror remake, who plays the projectionist?
In the opening to The Rocky Horror Picture Show: Let's Do The Time Warp Again, During "Science Fiction Double Feature," the Usherette shines a flashlight into the projection booth, showing it as empty. Then, a wizened old man comes into the frame to set up the projector. He's not seen again after this scene, and the character isn't listed in the credits. Who plays him?


Based on comments to the press about the movie and the ugliness of the rights issues, without solid evidence to the contrary, let's eliminate Richard O'Brien as an option. Also, it's not Sal Piro; he plays the Photographer in the wedding scene and is clearly shown and credited.

Philip Baker Hall could really use a haircut. :P

@NorrinRad Based on O'Brien's comments about the film, I think that can be eliminated. Adler essentially shut him out of the process. http://attitude.co.uk/richard-obrien-slams-rocky-horror-reboot-because-its-badly-cast/

It's not a clean photo but here it is lightened up. 

One possible answer is that it's Meat Loaf in an uncredited cameo. Here's a recent picture of the former Eddie:


That... doesn't really look like Meatloaf. But the pic is a bit dark. Is it possible to upload a clearer shot?

@Walt Not really—the room is intentionally dimly lit only by flashlight, and he's not in closeup for very long. I'll add another.
